# how html5 <audio> tag is responded by web servers

Tags: html, audio, server

Hi,
I developed a simple web server based on an open source C++ project.
In this web server there are a lot of wave files which I would like to show to web clients by using  tag of HTML 5.

I added wave files like following sample in html files which are sent to web browsers.

```
<audio controls>
<source src = "sound.wav" type="audio/wave">
</audio>
```

But Now I would like to know how web servers handle  tag and send stream data to web clients when web clients push play button.

I need to implement it from scratch in my web server.

I read a lot of posts but most of them just handle client side issues.

I need to deeply know how server side of a  request is handled.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you can see in MDN doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

> The HTML  element is used to embed sound content in documents. 
>   It may contain one or more audio sources, represented using the src
>   attribute or the  element; the browser will choose the most
>   suitable one.

The stream is not send to web clients when web clients push play button but is send when the page is loaded (lile all the media in a web page) 
you can control the execution using some attribute like :

**autoplay**

A Boolean attribute; if specified (even if the value is "false"!), 
the audio will automatically begin playback as soon as it can do so, without waiting for the entire audio file to finish downloading.

**buffered**

An attribute you can read to determine which time ranges of the media have been buffered. 
This attribute contains a TimeRanges object.

**preload**

This enumerated attribute is intended to provide a hint to the browser about what the author thinks will lead to the best user experience. It may have one of the following values:
none: indicates that the audio should not be preloaded;
metadata: indicates that only audio metadata (e.g. length) is fetched;
auto: indicates that the whole audio file could be downloaded, even if the user is not expected to use it;
the empty string: synonym of the auto value.

Comment: Thanks alot for answer, But as I write the web server part of project in C++, I would like to know how to send wav data to web browser.
now when I send whole wave file I got data abort or peer disconnection errors. I would like to know how I send wave file to web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Serving a file is something I bet you already know. To serve audio streaming, there are streaming protocols. One is ShoutCast and here you have a nice example in Python.

https://github.com/inforichland/PyCast